# Dual node Kafka cluster with docker - listeners misunderstandent

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, cluster-computing

I'm pretty new to Kafka and trying to run a cluster made up of (so far) 2 nodes. I'm using KRaft with hybrid mode. And I'm using the bitnami image. The two nodes because I need to understand the logic behind the interconnection between the nodes. I think I messed up the listeners and advertised.listeners config. I can see that nodes cannot reach controller ports (9082,9083) from the container log. So please see my compose.yml below. So what am I doing wrong? Thanks for any feedback, guys.

```
version: "2"

services:
  kafka-0:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/kafka:3.6
    container_name: kafka0
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9082:9082"
    networks:
      - kafka-net
    environment:
      # KRaft settings
      - KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID=0
      - KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=controller,broker
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=0@kafka-0:9082,1@kafka-1:9083
      - KAFKA_KRAFT_CLUSTER_ID=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
      # Listeners
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=KAFKA0://127.0.0.1:9092,KAFKA1://127.0.0.1:9093,CONTROLLER0://127.0.0.1:9082,CONTROLLER1://127.0.0.1:9083
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=KAFKA0://127.0.0.1:9092,KAFKA1://127.0.0.1:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=KAFKA0:PLAINTEXT,KAFKA1:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER0:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER1:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER0
      - KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=KAFKA0
      # Clustering
      - KAFKA_CFG_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=2
      - KAFKA_CFG_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR=2
      - KAFKA_CFG_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR=1
    volumes:
      - ./kafka_0_data:/bitnami/kafka
  kafka-1:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/kafka:3.6
    container_name: kafka1
    ports:
      - "9093:9093"
      - "9083:9083"
    networks:
      - kafka-net
    environment:
      # KRaft settings
      - KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID=1
      - KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=controller,broker
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=0@kafka-0:9082,1@kafka-1:9083
      - KAFKA_KRAFT_CLUSTER_ID=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
      # Listeners
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=KAFKA0://127.0.0.1:9092,KAFKA1://127.0.0.1:9093,CONTROLLER0://127.0.0.1:9082,CONTROLLER1://127.0.0.1:9083
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=KAFKA0://127.0.0.1:9092,KAFKA1://127.0.0.1:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=KAFKA0:PLAINTEXT,KAFKA1:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER0:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER1:PLAINTEXT
       - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER1
      - KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=KAFKA1
      # Clustering
      - KAFKA_CFG_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=2
      - KAFKA_CFG_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR=2
      - KAFKA_CFG_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR=1
    volumes:
      - ./kafka_1_data:/bitnami/kafka

networks:
  kafka-net:
    name: kafka-net
    external: true
```

My original thought was that I need to state all nodes of cluster (controller as well) in listeners and all brokers (no conotrllers) in advertised.listeners. But that was false apperently.